# Best way of forming url's automatically with PHP?

Tags: php

The question title is probably a bit misleading, but I can't think of a better way to phrase it.

To ensure a PHP application will run on any number of environments (as far as hyperlinks are concerned...) what is the best way to create the URL's?

My index.php in the root of the application references a base.php (controller) file that handles all requests.

So I've been using:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/url/to/file/i/want.php";
```

Is this the correct way to do it, or is there a better way? This works since every request originates from the index.php file...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: I always stick to relative paths if at all possible. I think it is the best way to guarantee everything is always accessible everywhere.

Comment: Why don't you just use relative paths? Assuming the directory and file structure doesn't change, it will work just fine on any number of environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work OK, or simply use relative paths.

You can also implement alternative approaches, for example you could have your hyperlinks as:

```
// this part could be established in a shared header/include/global variable for your scripts
$site_domain = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$site[url][full] .= "s";}
$site_domain  .= "://";
$site_domain =$site_domain .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

// you would then have links in your scripts coded as: $site_domain."/cleanurl/
```

$site_domain gives you the base domain reference, dynamic to wherever the scripts are hosted, you can then make your links: `$site_domain."/cleanurl/";`

Where '`cleanurl`' is a context based reference to the page you wish to load (e.g. 'news', as in www.mydomain.com/news/).

You can then use .htaccess and Apache mod_rewrite to handle where these URLs subsequently point:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cleanurl/$ /url/to/file/i/want.php [NC,L]
```

Because relative paths are used from the root directory in .htaccess, once setup, you should never need to make changes.

Another bonus of this is you also end up with 'clean', 'readable' links - and if you move where scripts are located in relation to your file structure, you dont have to go though all scripts that link to them and edit the links individually- you only have to change a single line in your .htaccess.

Comment: Ergo: Thanks for taking the time to write that. I probably should have been a bit clearer about my question. In my particular example I was referring to including specifically php files - I fully utilize all that mod_rewrite for apache has to offer with user-facing url's. Are there any pitfalls of using the example I gave? It seems cleaner (to me at least) than some of the methods posted here...

Comment: Not at all- if thats the case there is no pitfall in using your method, you could use relative references (i.e. ../myfiletoinclude.php) as an alternative which would mean you didnt need to have the initial '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']' specified, but its much of a muchness, both will work fine unless you start moving files/directories etc. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way either, but I tend to specify a $link_path and a $file_path in my code, I then use these for links on the page and includes/requires respectively.

This way I know that it will always work as I expect it to

```
$link_path = './';
$file_path = './';

// Show a link
echo '<a href="' . $link_path . 'my_file.php">Go to my_file.php</a>';

// Include a file
require_once($file_path . 'my_file.php');
```

This way it makes it flexible for me, especially if I'm using mod_rewrite to rewrite URLs